# Looping through a function to plot several subplots, Python

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I have variables `x` and `y`

```
def function(a,b):
    x = x[(x>a)*(x<b)]
    y = y[(y<a)*(y>b)]

    # perform some fitting routine using curve_fit on x and y

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    phist,xedge,yedge,img = ax.hist2d(x,y,bins=20,norm=LogNorm())
    im = ax.imshow(phist,cmap=plt.cm.jet,norm=LogNorm(),aspect='auto')
    fig.colorbar(im,ax=ax)
    fig.show()
```

All works fine. But **I have 6 pairs of different input parameters `a` and `b`. I would like to somehow call `function(a,b)` using a loop and plot the six different `x` and `y`** (corresponding to the 6 input pairs) **as 6 subplots.**

like we do

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(231) # x vs y for a1,b1
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(232) # x vs y for a2,b2
....
ax6 = fig.add_subplot(236) # x vs y for a6,b6
```

I would like to get an idea of how to proceed to get the final subplot!

I know that it can be done manually by specifying different variables, like `x1` and `y1` for the first input pair `a` and `b` and so on for the other 6 pairs `(x2,y2...,x6,y6)`. But it will be a very lengthy and confusing code.

Answer (score 3):

The key is using the three parameter form of subplot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Build a list of pairs for a, b
ab = zip(range(6), range(6))

#iterate through them
for i, (a, b) in enumerate(ab):
    plt.subplot(2, 3, i+1)
    #function(a, b)
    plt.plot(a, b)

plt.show()
```

You'll just have to take the call to `figure` out of the function.

Comment: can you elaborate further?

Comment: I've changed the answer to be completely self-contained and to operate on a list of pairs `ab`. This code runs fine on my machine. You can comment the `plt.plot` and substitute the `function` call where I've put it commented.

Answer (score 3):

Use `plt.subplots` instead of `plt.subplot` (note the "s" at the end).  `fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)` will create a figure with 2x3 group of subplots, where `fig` is the figure, and `axs` is a 2x3 numpy array where each element is the axis object corresponding to the axis in the same position in the figure (so `axs[1, 2]` is the bottom-right axis).

You can then either use a pair of loops to loop over each row then each axis in that row:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
for i, row in enumerate(axs):
   for j, ax in enumerate(row):
       ax.imshow(foo[i, j])
fig.show()
```

Or you can use `ravel` to flatten the rows and whatever you want to get the data from:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2, 3)
foor = foo.ravel()
for i, ax in enumerate(axs.ravel()):
    ax.imshow(foor[i])
fig.show()
```

Note that `ravel` is a view, not a copy, so this won't take any additional memory.